# How to avoid vertical gaps between table header cells in material-UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have vertical gaps between header cells in the MUI table. How to get rid of them?

Here is an reproduction of the bug in codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-material-table-sticky-header-forked-euilo3?file=/tsconfig.json

I tried applying styles:

```
    border: "none",
    borderCollapse: "collapse",
    margin: 0,
```

The bug appears only at certain resolutions and when scrolling the table.
[image: Material-UI header vertical gaps]

Answer (score 0):

When inspecting element, I can see `padding: 6px 16px;` on both `th` and `td` elements. So the extra gap is actually correct because it's applied for both header cell and row cell

[image]

You can just set `padding:0` or any value to change the header cell gap:

```css
 border: "none",
 borderCollapse: "collapse",
 margin: 0,
 padding: 0,
```

But you'll have to do the same for the row cell as well to keep them aligned.

Comment: I added "padding: 0" but it only removed the padding and the problem with gaps in the header still persists.

Comment: Sorry but not entirely sure what the problem is, so in the forked example I have here https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-material-table-sticky-header-forked-nyjtem?file=/src/HeadCell.tsx the left white space or gap in the header is gone when adding "padding: 0". What other gaps are still persisting?